# Angular 2 Output Binding not working

Tags: angular

I try to write my first Angular 2 App. I'm trying to create an Output Binding, but it doesn't work and I found no helpfull solution.

I trigger the function setZoom() from the inner component, and now the zoomChanged() function from the outer component should be triggert, but nothing happens. Same with setSize().

Here's my inner component:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'vk-editor-layer-manager',
  templateUrl: './layer-manager.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./layer-manager.component.styl']
})
export class LayerManagerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output('zoomChange') zoomChangeEvent: EventEmitter<number>;
  @Output('sizeChange') sizeChangeEvent: EventEmitter<any>;


  prefZoom: number = 50;

  constructor() {
    this.zoomChangeEvent = new EventEmitter();
    this.sizeChangeEvent = new EventEmitter();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  setZoom(newZoom: number){
    this.prefZoom = newZoom;
    this.zoomChangeEvent.emit(newZoom);
  }
  setSize(newWidth: number, newHeight: number){
    this.sizeChangeEvent.emit({Width: newWidth, Height: newHeight});
  }

}
```

Inner components template

```
<section>
  <header>
    Einstellungen
  </header>
  <div>
    <label for="prefWidth">Breite:</label>
    <input type="number" id="prefWidth" #EPrefWidth value="1024" /><br />
    <label for="prefHeight">Höhe:</label>
    <input type="number" id="prefHeight" #EPrefHeight value="1024" /><br />
    <button (click)="setSize(EPrefWidth?.value, EPrefHeight?.value)">Speichern</button>
    <hr />
    <label for="prefZoom">Zoom</label>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="300" id="prefZoom" #EPrefZoom (change)="setZoom(EPrefZoom.value)" [value]="prefZoom" />
    <span class="link" (click)="setZoom(50)">50%</span>
    <span class="link" (click)="setZoom(100)">100%</span>
    <span class="link" (click)="setZoom(150)">150%</span>
    <span class="link" (click)="setZoom(200)">200%</span>
    <span class="link" (click)="setZoom(250)">250%</span>
    <span class="link" (click)="setZoom(300)">300%</span>
    <br />
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <header>
    Layer hinzufügen
  </header>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum
  </div>
</section>
```

And here is the outer component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'vk-editor-rendering-engine',
  templateUrl: './rendering-engine.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rendering-engine.component.styl']
})
export class RenderingEngineComponent implements OnInit {

  canvas = {
    width: 1024,
    height: 1024,
    zoom: 50
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  zoomChanged(newZoom: number){
    this.canvas.zoom = newZoom;

    console.log(this.canvas);
  }

  sizeChanged(newWidth: number, newHeight: number){
    this.canvas.width = newWidth;
    this.canvas.height = newHeight;

    console.log(this.canvas);
  }

}
```

And outer component template:

```
<div id="workarea">
  <div id="canvasContainer">

  </div>
</div>
<vk-editor-layer-manager (zoomChange)="zoomChanged($event)"
                         (sizeChange)="sizeChanged($event.Width, $event.Height)"
></vk-editor-layer-manager>
```

Comment: Where do you call `setZoom` ?

Comment: I have a element in the inner component template with a click-event

Comment: Can you confirm that when you `console.log(this)` inside those events your `this` refers to your component? Maybe call another `console.log(1)` function to test it if it works.

Comment: console.log(this) in setZoom() prints this `LayerManagerComponent {prefZoom: 100, zoomChangeEvent: EventEmitter, sizeChangeEvent: EventEmitter, ngOnInit: function, setZoom: function, …}`

Comment: Seems to work fine here... http://plnkr.co/edit/Mdzs69qhg12VVLwivpWO?p=preview

Comment: Yes, it works fine. Strange thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through the comment of [@AJT_82](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42872936/angular-2-output-binding-not-working/42873879#comment72851392_42872936) I found the answer.

In the app.module.ts file (the main file) I removed LayerManagerComponent from bootstrap array. And now it works fine. But I don't know, why.

Answer (score -2):

```
    import {Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'vk-editor-layer-manager',
      templateUrl: './layer-manager.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./layer-manager.component.styl']
    })
    export class LayerManagerComponent implements OnInit {
      @Output() zoomChangeEvent: EventEmitter();
      @Output() sizeChangeEvent: EventEmitter();


      prefZoom: number = 50;

      ngOnInit() {
      }

      setZoom(newZoom: number){
        this.prefZoom = newZoom;
        this.zoomChangeEvent.emit(newZoom);
      }
      setSize(newWidth: number, newHeight: number){
        this.sizeChangeEvent.emit(new setSizeEventObject(newWidth, newHeight});
      }

    }

   export class setSizeEventObject {
      public Width: number;
      public Height: number;
      constructor(_width : number , _height : number){
         this.Width = _width;
         this.Height = _height;
      }
   }



 sizeChanged(event : setSizeEventObject){
    this.canvas.width = event.newWidth;
    this.canvas.height = event.newHeight;

    console.log(this.canvas);
  }
```

Comment: Ok, but what is your explanation for this?